# In Ethereum, is it possible for a malicious client to duplicate a coin by double executing a transaction?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, blockchain, ethereum-classic, consensus

Is it possible a scenario in which a malicious client executes two transactions with the same nonce of a specific account and copies and sends coins?

Suppose users A, B, and C have the following balances:

A: 3, B: 0, C: 0

Tx1 : { nonce:1, data : { receiver: B, amount: 3 } } from User 'A'

Tx2 : { nonce:1, data : { receiver: C, amount: 3 } } from User 'A'

Assuming that both transactions are executed and included in the blockchain, is the following balance status possible?

A: 0, B: 3, C: 3

Is it possible for a malicious client to attempt consensus by including those two transactions in the blockchain as in the following situation?

Comment: No, that's exactly what the nonce is for (must increment by 1 upon every transaction of a given account).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By the way, is that even if you are using a malicious variant client? For example, if we consider the BFT consensus algorithm, the meaning of the faulty node is that it can send a consensus message about a malicious state. Is that the case impossible?